# EVE - 500 Internal server error on POST request

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, eve

While inserting a document to the eve's corresponding endpoint there is a 
`pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred` but the document I'm sending is not a batch but a single object.

Here is the document I'm trying to POST with https://pastebin.com/CXstV7PW

And here is the validation schema https://pastebin.com/5wxiPQX5

I have manually checked the fields and everything should be fine but regardless of the method for sending(postman, requests etc.) the result is the same.

Here is the response to the client:

```
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred</p>
```

Any idea what could it be?

Comment: Even with the error, the document is stored at database, as you may already know. But, debugging the error, I've found this error message: `language override unsupported: eng`.

So, for some reason, changing `language` value from `eng` to `en`, in your example document solved the 500 error problem and posted OK.

Comment: @gcw That is some behavior but thanks to you I was able to post the document. With the error message I found why it does so. MongoDB has support for document translation ```https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/``` and uses the ```language``` field by default